# How do I manually add a project to the build path of another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project which won't compile due to an unresolvable reference from another project's artifact.

When I run eclipse:eclipse and open it up it shows an auto fix suggestion of "Add project 'project2' to build path of 'project1'". If I click this everything works. So project1 can clearly see my project2 reference, but doesn't quite use it as expected.

However, once I delete all the files generated for eclipse the error resumes because whatever reference eclipse created has been removed. How can I get this project2 in the project1 build path manually. I already have it listed in the pom as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you delete the eclipse related files?

Comment: Do you have maven nature to both your projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "Project properties > Maven" menu you should check "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects".

Comment: Try to uncheck, save, check and check (i call this kind of weird things The Eclipse Magic".
Else you can try in "Project properties > Project references" to specify it manually. But for me, it works just with the "resolve dependencies..." option.

Comment: Even more, in the project properties section "Java Build Path", "Projects" tab, you can add the other projects that the other projects need to compile.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run eclipse:eclipse[...]

This sounds like you are using the Maven Eclipse plugin. You should probably rather use [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), which is the recommended way to integrate with Maven now. This will also obviate the need to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Instead, just import your Maven project into Eclipse, and it will pick up everything automatically.

After you set "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" as described in polypiel's answer, things should just work (TM).

Answer (score 0):

If you have maven nature to both your projects, you should do `mvn clean install` to both the projects, so they will be installed in your local repository and will be available for other projects to use as dependencies. Or just right click to both the projects in eclipse and choose Run As --> Maven install